# How do I change the format of all pictures in a PowerPoint 2010 presentation?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2010

How do I change the format of all of the pictures in a PowerPoint 2010 presentation?  I know how to change the format of one picture, but there are over 40 pictures in the deck and I do not want to have to change each one manually.

The change I want to make is simple: I want to add a border to each picture.  How the border is added or what it looks like doesn't matter much.  Right now I am right-clicking on the picture and clicking on Format Picture/Glow and Soft Edges and adding a 5pt Glow with a transparency of 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This little macro will do the job for you:

```
Sub AddPictureBorders()
' Before running this, apply the style you want to one picture
' then use the formatting paintbrush to pick up the formatting
' This will apply the formatting to each picture.
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim oSl As Slide

For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
        With oSh
            ' ignoring linked pictures, OLE objects
            ' and such
            If .Type = msoPicture Then
                .Apply
            End If
        End With
    Next
Next

End Sub
```