# Can you format charts from multiple slides in a single step?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

Related to this post: [How do I change the format of all pictures in a PowerPoint 2010 presentation?](https://superuser.com/questions/355277/how-do-i-change-the-format-of-all-pictures-in-a-powerpoint-2010-presentation).

But instead of editing formats for pictures in a single slide, I would like to edit **charts in multiple slides**. Is there a simple method to achieve this?

Essentially, I would like to change the existing properties to the following:

- *Chart Area Size*:

  ```
  Height = 7.98 cm
  Width  = 14.06 cm
  ```
- *Chart Area Position*:

  ```
  Horizontal = 9.5 cm (from Top Left Corner)
  Vertical   = 1.22 cm (from Top Left Corner)
  ```

I'm aware this could probably be achieved using macros but I'm not particularly hot on my macro skills at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only change shapes on the current slide or, if they inherit their properties from placeholders on the master, by modifying the master or layout that controls them.

So, for instance, if your charts are in content placeholders, then changing the size/location of the placeholder on the slide layout should get you there.

Otherwise, it's one at a time.  Having to match up the size/pos of shapes from one slide to the next is so common that a little routine to do it was one of the first macros I ever wrote.  I've long since incorporated it into the free version of a PowerPoint add-in that includes it and other useful tools

It's called the PPTools StarterSet, available at http://www.pptools.com/starterset/

It'd allow you to pick up and "memorize" the size/pos of one chart and then apply the same size/pos to any other charts with a single click.

[Update} The tool I referred to above is only only of the tools in StarterSet, which is still available. I've just spun this particular tool off as a standalone that now installs on the Ribbon (and can be customized onto other parts of the ribbon or QAT), is 32-and 64-bit compatible, and has a few other improvements and bug-fixes. Still free. Available here: pptools.com/free/index.html

Comment: +1, Thank you very much! Your comment about the placeholder has helped a great deal but I will also take a look at your add-in :)

Comment: A minor update: The tool I referred to above is only only of the tools in StarterSet, but it's easily the most popular. I've just spun it off as a standalone that's now on the Ribbon (and can be customized onto other parts of the ribbon or QAT), is 32-and 64-bit compatible, and has a few other improvements and bug-fixes.  Still free. Available here:  http://www.pptools.com/free/index.html

Comment: Thanks Steve, that's good to know! I will try this out at some point but you should consider [editing](http://superuser.com/posts/972138/edit) your post to include this update :)

Comment: Good suggestion, @Joseph Done.